Webservice SOAP ASMX downt work in Android and iOS .net MAUI 8.0
I try to consume a SOAP WebService on an Android device and it shows the error "Connection failure". On iOS, the error is "dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform", even with AOT enabled. It works normally on Windows Machine connect to webservice.
Error at line 19 from MauiSoapConsumer/MainPage.xaml.cs
`using WsCalculator;
namespace MauiSoapConsumer
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
private CalculatorSoapClient _service;
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
        _service = new CalculatorSoapClient(new CalculatorSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration());
    }

    private async void Somar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int.TryParse(Number1.Text, out int numb1);
        int.TryParse(Number2.Text, out int numb2);

        LblResult.Text = (await _service.AddAsync(numb1, numb2)).ToString();
    }

    private async void Subtrair(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int.TryParse(Number1.Text, out int numb1);
        int.TryParse(Number2.Text, out int numb2);

        LblResult.Text = (await _service.SubtractAsync(numb1, numb2)).ToString();
    }

    private async void Dividir(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int.TryParse(Number1.Text, out int numb1);
        int.TryParse(Number2.Text, out int numb2);

        LblResult.Text = (await _service.DivideAsync(numb1, numb2)).ToString();
    }

    private async void Multiplicar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int.TryParse(Number1.Text, out int numb1);
        int.TryParse(Number2.Text, out int numb2);

        LblResult.Text = (await _service.MultiplyAsync(numb1, numb2)).ToString();
    }
}

}`
Repro project: https://github.com/markos-jr/MauiSoapConsumer

these are two completely different errors that need to be handled separately.  The first sounds like a simple connectivity issue between Android and your server.

Yes, @Jason. Android I resolved with this  

But iOS its the problem! I think so its about AOT compilation, but I checked this and problem persists. Can you help?

Another question on PlatformNotSupportedException with MAUI 8.0 on iOS was raised in the past couple of hours. The asker posted an answer in the same minute.
